# Converting a repeating binary number to decimal

Tags: floating-point, binary

How do I represent 0.1011111.... or 0.10(1) as a fraction a/b? 
With a & b being integers.

I have being trying this method

x = 0.10(1)
x = 10.(1) / 4

Now y = 10.(1)

2y = 101.(1)

which implies 2y - y = 91
y = 91

x = 91/4
But a = 91 & b = 4 is wrong.

How do I go about to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to observe that the numbers are still in binary. Thus in decimal you get that the integer part of `y` is `2` and of `2y` is `5`, so that in the difference `y=3`.

Note that in binary `0.1(1)=1`, just as in decimal `0.9(9)=1`. Thus in an alternative way, `x` is exactly `0.11` binary, which is `1/2+1/4=3/4`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as follows:

x = (0.1011111)<sub>2</sub>

#### Representing above binary term in decimal gives us:

x = 1/2<sup>1</sup> + 0/2<sup>2</sup> + 1/2<sup>3</sup> + 1/2<sup>4</sup> + ... )
x = 1/2 + 1/2<sup>2</sup>*(1/2<sup>1</sup> + **1/2<sup>2</sup>** + 1/2<sup>3</sup> + ... ) 

If we ignore the term marked in bold in above equation, the term in parenthesis becomes **x**, so we can say the term in parenthesis is equal to **(x+1/2<sup>2</sup>)**

x = 1/2 + 1/2<sup>2</sup>*(x+1/2<sup>2</sup>) 
x = 1/2 + x/4 + 1/16 

Solve above equation 
3x/4 = 9/16 
x = 3/4

Comment: Minor error: that `1/8` should be `1/16`. That way when you solve you'll get `x=3/4`, which agrees with @LutzL's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generalization of this problem to the frequent situation of repeting patterns.

Assume x=0.001100110011..., where pattern 0011 is repeated infinitely.

Let a be the pattern (0011 for x) and k be its length (ie 4 for x).

x = a×2^-k+a×2^-2k+...
  = a×2^-k×∑<sub><sub>i=0</sub></sub><sup><sup>∞</sup></sup> (2^-k)^i
  = a×2^-k×lim<sub>n→∞</sub>(1-(2^-k)^n)/(1-2^-k)
as x is the sum of a geometric serie with a 2^k ratio.

When n goes to ∞, (2^-k)^n goes to zero and we have
x = a×2^-k/(1-2^-k) = a/(2^k-1)

If x=0.11111..., a=1, k=1 and x=1/(2-1)=1 and we get the result already presented (in a much simpler way!) by LutzL that answers the original question.

But we can solve more complex problems with any repeating pattern.
For instance if x=0.001100110011..., we have a=0011=3 and k=4.
Hence x=3/(2^-4-1)=1/5=0.2

The generalization to the situation where the repetitive pattern is preceded by a non repeating sequence is immediate.